# Checking if the result of a map contains a false value

Tags: vector, clojure

When I'm comparing, **for example**, the following line (These numbers are sample data and can vary).

`(map < '[1 2 3 4 5 6] [4 2 3 4 5 9])`

I want be able to check if the output contains a false boolean. If it does I want to do some logic, otherwise I want to do some different logic.

This is what I have so far:

```
(if(map < '[1 2 3 4 5 6] [4 2 3 4 5 9])
// True logic
// False logic)
```

Thus far it always goes to the true line and never the false line with what ever data I insert. Is there a way I can acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `some` with the predicate `false?`:

```
(some false? (map < '[1 2 3 4 5 6] [4 2 3 4 5 9])) ;;=> true

(if (some false? (map < '[1 2 3 4 5 6] [4 2 3 4 5 9]))
  'True
  'False) ;;=> True
```